# How do I call a serverside function from javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, .net-3.5

I have a javascript function from where I am trying to call the serverside function   `WebSchedule.Client.RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged`. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function RowSelected(sender, args) 
     {
         var dataKeyValue = args.getDataKeyValue("Order_No");
         document.getElementById("txtOrderno").value = dataKeyValue;
         WebSchedule.Client.RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args);
     }
 </script>
```

However, I get an error "WebSchedule is undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And you are sure you are calling this pagemethod from with an aspx page and not an ascx usercontrol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out so called [page methods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx).

Btw, is this supposed to be server side method or client side?

```
function RowSelected(sender, args) { 
    var dataKeyValue = args.getDataKeyValue("Order_No");      
    document.getElementById("txtOrderno").value = dataKeyValue;
    WebSchedule.Client.RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args); 
}
```

So - seems to me that's a javascript function.

As far as i understand, RadScriptManager inherits from System.Web.UI.ScriptManager. This is what EnablePageMethods prop does:
"Gets or sets a value that indicates whether **public static** page methods in an ASP.NET page can be called from client script."

Those words in bold means - you won't see any control in that serverside method cause of lack of viewstate.

Therefore - consider using Update Panel control (i've got no ideas how it goes together with telerik controls) or make sure that your serverside method is completely stateless (pass needed data through javascript function).

Anyway - seems to me that you should investigate nature of page methods closer.

Comment: i have done that and in the <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" EnablePageMethods="true">
pagemethods are true and it still doesnt work

Comment: the Bottom line is the serverside method

Comment: Thanks for that great feeling when you help to someone. :)

Answer (score 1):

Client =/= Server

Look into Asynchronous Javascript and XML.

Answer (score 1):

Your server side pagemethods must have the WebMethod attribute and be declared public static.

Then using javascript they can be called using this syntax: PageMethods.MethodName()

Comment: This will fail, cause public static methods knows nothing about viewstate => gridview.

Comment: You're right about viewstate but the question is just about calling a server side method - nothing to do with viewstate. Obviously server side events can't be directly called with javascript.

Comment: this seems to have woked thank you however i am now running out of stack space

Comment: do i need to enable viewstates?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the server side method?

Comment: the server side method access's our database to get all of the info that is stored in the record selected for editing and also then populates a RadCalendar control to inform the user that they have x days available for booking a selected job from the grid

Comment: I think an easier way of doing this would be to use Teleriks built in AJAX. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxajaxmanager.html
Or consider using update panels as suggested by Arnis L.

Comment: thanks i have gone down the update panel route and am now sorting the issue out that way thank you for your help on this

Comment: Just be careful with update panel. It can ruin performance a lot if used incorrectly. :)